# Why don't we require only straight line approaches to check differentiability at a complex point?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

I know that counter examples exist, so this must be wrong. I just want to know what's wrong with this reasoning:

If we consider the limit:

$$L=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+h(\cos{p}+i\sin{p})) - f(z)}{h(\cos{p}+i\sin{p})}$$

If this limit is independent of $p$, then clearly, the complex function $f$ has the same derivative for all straight-line approaches to the point $z$.

Now, I want to show that, if the straight line approaches give the same derivative, then approaching the point $z$ along any other curve must also give the same derivative (this has to be wrong because counter examples exist).

Let $z=a+ib$. Suppose this point lies on the curve $y=g(x)$. If we change $a$ by a small amount $h$ along the curve, then we arrive at the point $a+h+i(g(a+h))$. Then the derivative by approaching the point along this curve should be:

$$L'=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+h+i(g(a+h)-g(a)))-f(z)}{h+i(g(a+h)-g(a))}$$

Consider $h+i(g(a+h)-g(a))$. This equals $h'(\cos{d}+i\sin{d})$, where $h'=\sqrt{h^2+(g(a+h)-g(a))^2}$, and $d=\arctan{\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}}=\arctan{g'(a)}$. As $h$ tends to zero, $h'$ also tends to zero. So, limit $L'$ becomes:

$$\lim_{h'\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+h'(\cos{d}+i\sin{d})) - f(z)}{h'(\cos{d}+i\sin{d})}$$

This is the same limit as limit $L$.

Comment: If you know that counterexamples exist, then why don't you plug one of those counterexamples into your proof, check it line by line, and see where it goes wrong?

Comment: @bof I want an explanation for why this proof doesn't  work in general, and not for just one counter example. There might be so many cases of functions which specific counter-examples don't satisfy.

Comment: @bof I tried a counter example in which we check differentiability at 0 along the curve $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$. In this case, $g'(0)$ is not defined. Is this the only case where my proof doesn't work (i.e. when $g'(a)$ is not defined)?

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950615/72031